# jQuery Animation not getting stopped

Tags: jquery

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Xpd/)

Please take a look at the above fiddle. Basically I want to make the blinking LED stop (`opacity` back to `1`) animating once I click on `stop!` button.

Weirdly enough, it doesn't work all the time. The animation keeps on rolling even if the `stop` button is clicked.

**Things I tried**:

1. **.stop()**
2. **.stop(true)**
3. **.finish()**
4. **.clearQueue().stop()**
5. **.clearQueue().finish()**

Any clue what may be wrong.?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `.stop(true, true)` ?

Comment: Yup. Tried that as well. It seems to be working the first time but not afterwards. You can try hitting the start & stop button multiple time to reproduce this.

Comment: Change your own `animate()` function to some else name

Comment: @Pavlo Is there any restriction when using pre-defined method of jQuery?

Comment: I don't know exactly, but I know that people had a lot of problems related to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work using clearQueue() and finish(), see if it's fit your needs:

```
$('#start').click( function(){
    animation();
});

$('#stop').click(function() {  
    $led = $('.led-green');
    $led.animate({opacity: 1},100, function(){
                        $led.clearQueue();
                        $led.finish();
                    });

});

function animation(){

     $('.led-green').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500)
                    .animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function(){
                        animation();
                    });
}
```

You can check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Xpd/4/)

Answer (score 2):

see [<kbd>demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/D8w6s/)

in `stop()` function remove this line it will call `animate()` function again

```
//$('.led-green').animate({opacity: 1},1000);
```

change this

```
$('#stop').click(function() {    
    $('.led-green').stop();
    $('.led-green').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I want it to revert it back to full opacity. If you try to stop when opacity is less it is not coming back to its original state if I remove that line of code.

Answer (score -1):

Please check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f2Xpd/1/)

```
var animation;
$('#start').click( function(){
   animate();
});

$('#stop').click(function() {    
  $('.led-green').animate({opacity: 1},100);
  animation.stop();
});

function animate(){
   animation = $('.led-green').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1000);

   animation.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function(){
   animate()
});
}
```